# Spark Structured Streaming Memory Bound

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am processing a stream of 100 Mb/s average load. I have six executors with each having 12 Gb of memory allocated. However, due to data load, I am getting Out of Memory errors (Error 52) in the spark executors in few minutes. It seems even though Spark dataframe is conceptually [unbounded](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-concepts) it is bounded by total executor memory?

My idea here was to save dataframe/stream as an in parquet in about every five minutes. However, it seems spark won't have a direct mechanism to purge the dataframe after that?

```
val out = df.
  writeStream.
  format("parquet").
  option("path", "/applications/data/parquet/customer").
  option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoints/customer/checkpoint").
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(300.seconds)).
  outputMode(OutputMode.Append).
  start
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no direct way to do this. As [this conflicts with the general Spark model that operations be rerunnable in case of failure](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20568).

However I would share the same sentiment of the [comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20568?focusedCommentId=16356929&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16356929) at 08/Feb/18 13:21 on this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20568).